# Git pull enforce authentication

Tags: git, github

I am trying to learn some basics of github. I want to enforce authentication whenever a git pull request is made. Is it possible to do in a public repository?

This is my public test repository
https://github.com/SanthanaRajagopalan/JenkinTest

When I try to clone it in any machine using this url
https://github.com/SanthanaRajagopalan/JenkinTest.git

It doesn't ask for any credentials when I do a pull.

Am I missing some configuration or git doesn't prompt for a password when its a public repository?

Comment: Why would you need credentials is the repository is public?

Comment: @Makoto That requirement was part of another requirement of mine. The company that I work have a private repository which prompts for credentials each and every time I do a pull. I am trying to set up Jenkins for that environment. So I needed a test environment to actually set up things in a similar way

Answer (score 0):

When you execute `git pull` locally, you're only affecting the copy of the repository on your machine, not the copy on GitHub's servers. GitHub will require authentication to write to their copy of the repository (either using `git push` locally or merging a Pull Request in the web interface).

Answer (score 0):

only autorized users can make a push to your repository in this way you always make a push with SanthanaRajagopalan user loged, if i try make a push with mi user i can't do it, gihib send me the next message:

remote: Permission to SanthanaRajagopalan/JenkinTest.git denied to mottaman85.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/SanthanaRajagopalan/JenkinTest/': The requested URL returned error: 403

this command show the user is loged

git config --global user.name